# Powershell output content of two arrays based on a join

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv

I am querying sql to gather some nintex information from the SharePoint Nintex database. Nintex only holds SharePoint siteid. So I need powershell to get me the url (and some additional data) from the results output by sql 
I can do this using the :

```
$GUIDS = ($DS.Tables[0] | select -ExpandProperty  siteid) | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
foreach($line in $guids)
{Get-Spsite -identity $line  | Select -property ID, URL, OWner, Hostname | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\url.csv -NoTypeInformation }
```

But I also need the csv output to include the workflowinitiator, workflowname, and activityname  that I have in the array $workflowdetails.

How do I combine the output into one and export to csv
This is what I have so far:

```
[CmdletBinding()]

param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
 [string]$SQLServerInstance,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string]$NintexConfigDBName
)
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$ConnectionTimeout = 30
$Query =  "SELECT DISTINCT i.workflowname,i.siteid,i.workflowinitiator, a.activityname FROM dbo.workflowinstance 
i inner join WorkflowProgress P on I.InstanceID=P.InstanceID inner join Activities A on P.ActivityID=A.ActivityID WHERE a.activityname IN ('Call web service','Execute SQL','Query LDAP','Query XML', 'Start workflow in Nintex Workflow Cloud ',  'Update XML  ', 'Web request ', 'Capture document set version  ', 'Copy to file share',  'Create list', 'Declare as record ', 'Delete drafts', 'Delete item ', 'Delete multiple items', 'Delete previous versions', 'Discard check out ','Query list','Send document set to repository',  'Send document to repository','Set approval status ','Set item permissions', 'Undeclare as record  ', 'Update multiple items', 'Action set', 'Commit pending changes', 'Run parallel actions', 'State machine ', 'Pause for...  ', 'Pause until...  ', 'Wait for check out status change ', 'Wait for item update ', 'Create site  ','Create site collection','Decommission site collection ',  'Delete site', 'Publish Workflow', 'Assign Flexi task', 'Complete workflow task ' ) "

$QueryTimeout = 120

$conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$ConnectionString = "Server={0};database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $SQLServerInstance,$NintexConfigDBName,$ConnectionTimeout
$conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString
$conn.Open()
$cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
$ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
$da.fill($ds)
$conn.Close()
$DS.Tables[0]  
$workflowdetails = ($DS.Tables[0] | select -ExpandProperty  siteid, workflowinitiator, workflowname,activityname ) | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
$GUIDS = ($DS.Tables[0] | select -ExpandProperty  siteid) | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
foreach($line in $guids)
{Get-Spsite -identity $line  | Select -property ID, URL, OWner, Hostname | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\url.csv -NoTypeInformation }
```

Comment: You can append `$workflowdetails` to `url.csv` by using `-append` and `-Force` parameters. Something like this --
`$workflowdetails | export-csv -Path c:\temp\url.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the sites exported to the same CSV file, just use `Export-Csv` *after* the loop:

So us this:

```
foreach ($line in $guids) {
    Get-Spsite -identity $line
} | Select ID, URL, OWner, Hostname | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\url.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

instead of this:

```
foreach ($line in $guids) {
    Get-Spsite -identity $line | Select -property ID, URL, OWner, Hostname | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\url.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

If you want to combine site data and SQL result, you basically must create some way of looking up the one thing while you output the other.

Hash tables are designed to look up things by a key very quickly, so storing all the sites in a hashtable makes sense:

```
$sitesById = @{}
foreach ($SiteID in $DS.Tables[0].SiteID) {
    $sitesById[$SiteID] = Get-Spsite -identity $SiteID
}
```

After that you can use `Select-Object` with calculated columns to add data from the SharePoint site to the SQL output.

```
$DS.Tables[0] |
    Select-Object siteid, workflowinitiator, workflowname, activityname,
        @{name="URL"; expression={ $sitesById[$_.siteid].URL }}
        @{name="Owner"; expression={ $sitesById[$_.siteid].Owner }},
        @{name="Hostname"; expression={ $sitesById[$_.siteid].Hostname }} |
    Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\url.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tonalak. I get it now.. I did this and it works now

Comment: If this was helpful to you, please upvote it. Upvotes are the "thank you, this helped me" of this site.

Answer (score 0):

```
[CmdletBinding()]

    param
    (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [string]$SQLServerInstance,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$NintexConfigDBName
    )
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
    $ConnectionTimeout = 30
    $Query =  "SELECT DISTINCT i.workflowname,i.siteid,i.workflowinitiator, a.activityname FROM dbo.workflowinstance 
    i inner join WorkflowProgress P on I.InstanceID=P.InstanceID inner join Activities A on P.ActivityID=A.ActivityID WHERE a.activityname IN ('Call web service','Execute SQL','Query LDAP','Query XML', 'Start workflow in Nintex Workflow Cloud ',  'Update XML  ', 'Web request ', 'Capture document set version  ', 'Copy to file share',  'Create list', 'Declare as record ', 'Delete drafts', 'Delete item ', 'Delete multiple items', 'Delete previous versions', 'Discard check out ','Query list','Send document set to repository',  'Send document to repository','Set approval status ','Set item permissions', 'Undeclare as record  ', 'Update multiple items', 'Action set', 'Commit pending changes', 'Run parallel actions', 'State machine ', 'Pause for...  ', 'Pause until...  ', 'Wait for check out status change ', 'Wait for item update ', 'Create site  ','Create site collection','Decommission site collection ',  'Delete site', 'Publish Workflow', 'Assign Flexi task', 'Complete workflow task ' ) "

    $QueryTimeout = 120

    $conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
    $ConnectionString = "Server={0};database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $SQLServerInstance,$NintexConfigDBName,$ConnectionTimeout
    $conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
    $cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
    $ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
    $da.fill($ds)
    $conn.Close()
    $DS.Tables[0]  

    foreach ($element in $DS.Tables[0])
    {

        $WFI = ($DS.Tables[0] | select -ExpandProperty   workflowinitiator)
        $WFN = ($DS.Tables[0] | select -ExpandProperty   workflowname )
        $WFA = ($DS.Tables[0] | select -ExpandProperty   activityname )
        $WFID = ($DS.Tables[0] | select -ExpandProperty   siteid )


            foreach($line in $WFID)

                    {
                    $siteURL= Get-Spsite -identity $line | Select -property  URL, OWner, Hostname 
                    }

                    $Properties = @{
                    WFInitiator = $WFI
                    WFname =$WFN
                    WFactivity = $WFA
                    SiteID = $WFID
                    siteURL = $siteURL.url
                    siteowner=$siteURL.owner
                    hostname =$siteURL.hostname
                    }
    $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $properties
    }
    $Results | Select-Object WFinitiator, WFname, WFactivity, siteid,siteurl, siteowner, hostname | export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path C:\temp\url.csv
```